# Non-blocking HTTP calls in Storm with php

Tags: web-crawler, nonblocking, apache-storm

I am evaluating to built a webcrawler using Storm (the real time framework, not the IDE). My Spout would deliver a Stream of URIs, which have to be called and retrieved in the first Bolt, which is written in php.

Coming from a node.js background, I know that it's possible to built such a functionality in a non-blocking way, using callbacks. My naive idea would be, to just configure a lot of Tasks for that Bolt, so that the resources can be fully used while some Taks are waiting for answers. The problem is, php is notorious to allocate a lot of resources for each process, and I have no idea, how Storm manages that internally and if this is a good idea.

Is a node.js-like behavior possible in this environment? Or do I have to switch to another language for this Bolt to achieve it (and if so, how do I do it)?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a web crawler that uses Storm & non-blocking HTTP calls, albeit in Java. We've been using it in production and it works pretty good.

We have a stream of URLs coming in from a spout, which is dispatched to crawler bolts. Each bolts will make non-blocking HTTP requests, on which I register a callback that will emit results to the output collectors. I.e. yes you can do non-blocking IO with Storm.

I'm not familiar with PHP development so I can't comment on that much, but whatever you'll do, it will probably perform quite poor compared to a JVM based language because of the inter process messaging.

Note: Output collectors are no longer thread safe in recent versions of Storm, so be sure to synchronize on them When you emit stuff asynchronously.